# eclipse cdt formatter is not behaving correctly for bool type in <stdbool.h>

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting

I have ran into a problem with eclipse cdt 3.8.0 formatter on debian. when it formats my code automatically the newline between functions returning bool and block comments is removed like the follow:
this a problem in C source files and only applies to bool type 
please help me correct this problem:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

/* my comment 1 */
void foo(void);

/* my comment 2 */bool is_valid(void);

/* my comment 3 */
int cool(void);
```

and I want this:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

/* my comment 1 */
void foo(void);

/* my comment 2 */
bool is_valid(void);

/* my comment 3 */
int cool(void);
```

When I comment `#include <stdbool.h>` and insert the following codes. the formatter act correctly

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

ofcourse when I insert the following codes instead of above code the problem still remains.

```
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

It seems that the formmater not acts correctly for Macros

Comment: A 50 rep. bounty for an editor formatting issue when you only have 188 rep. ?! This formatter issue must really annoy you !

Comment: Does the formatter understand C99 syntax? Can it be configured to do so? `bool` is a macro for `_Bool`; both were introduced in the C99 standard.

Comment: Yes It really annoys me I have to submit my code for a system with style checker and whenever I reformat the code I have to correct all functions with bool returns.

Comment: I have already defined C99 in makefile. but it seems the eclipse formatter consider the bool type an empty macro which is ridiculous.

Comment: To have a sample program, will this work? `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* my comment 1 */
void foo(void);

/* my comment 2 */
bool is_valid(void);

/* my comment 3 */
int cool(void);

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}

void foo(void) {
}

bool is_valid(void) {
  return true;
}

int cool(void) {
  return true;
}`

Comment: Defining C99 in the makefile (how, exactly?) probably just affects the compiler. For example, if you're using gcc, you might pass the argument `-std=c99`. That's not going to affect the behavior of the formatter, which is probably why it doesn't recognize `bool`.

Comment: Samaras=>No that does not work too I have this problem in both implementation and header file.

Comment: Thompson=> I have tested both -std=gnu99 and -std=c99 flags, the problem still remains. the compiling flags affects the formatter e.g. in c++11 the adding the proper flag make the formatter understand lambda function here it should understand bool type. but it doesn't understand. and the coloring of bool is not like other types too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a solution, however it is not a complete answer.
I noticed that it is a bug for eclipse cdt formatter not understanding bool type.
but when I use double slash comments instead of slash star comments the formatter does not join the two lines and since double slash comments are introduced in C99 it will work there.

```
/* my comment 1 */
void foo(void);

// my comment 2
bool is_valid(void);

/* my comment 3 */
int cool(void);
```

of course I think the above problem needs to be reported to the eclipse DEV team. does any one knows where it should be reported?

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I ran into a similar problem related to the `c99` bool and `stdbool.h`. The `cdt` project settings have a definition for the `__cplusplus` macro by default, which is used by `stdbool.h` to NOT define `bool`/`true`/`false` if the code is C++. Just delete that in project properties under "C/C++ Include Paths and Preprocessor Symbols".

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any entry in eclipse's menu that allow you to configure line wrapping for function prototypes.

I can only suggest you to use the search and replace within the eclipse, select all lines you want to edit, press CTRL+F, fill the search dialog with `*/` in the search field and `*/\n` in the replace field, check the 'regular expressions' box and click replace all.

Comment: This is not happening in the prototype only. this is also a problem in function declaration too. I think the eclipse misunderstand bool data type for C language. And the problem is that If I manually correct them by find and search, whenever I reformat the source code the problem regenerates.

Comment: What is the eclipse version you are using?